# Sonata Admin Bundle - Change field label in vendor bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have vendor bundle with some admin. And I want change form field label, but I don't know how I can do this.

I used Compiler Pass, but it's doesn't help me.

How I can do it?

Thanks.

Comment: It depend on where is that label inside the bundle. Could be in a translation file, in a twig template or also in the form definition. ???

Comment: label - is hardcode text, like array('label' => 'Name') for field settings

Comment: has you checked http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#forms